# solr, idexing of page/url with multiple json documents

Tags: json, solr, lotus-domino

I would like to index page that has JSON array as content.

If I try to post it with command:

> bin/post -c gettingstarted http://localhost/index.nsf/api/data/collections/unid/93867b71911dd9b6c125802a005dba7b  -recursive 1 -delay 1

and in page, there is something like:

[
  {
      "@href":"/index.nsf/api/data/collections/unid/93867b71911dd9b6c125802a005dba7b/unid/4E584A172BD984BFC125802A005E0FF7",
      "@link":
      {
          "rel":"document",
          "href":"/index.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/4E584A172BD984BFC125802A005E0FF7"
      },
      "@entryid":"1-4E584A172BD984BFC125802A005E0FF7",
      "@unid":"4E584A172BD984BFC125802A005E0FF7",
      "@noteid":"8F6",
      "@position":"1",
      "@siblings":5,
      "@form":"book",
      "author":"ivo andri\u0107",
      "title":"na drini \u0107uprija",
      "isbn":"121233131",
      "stars":5
  },
  {
      "@href":"/index.nsf/api/data/collections/unid/93867b71911dd9b6c125802a005dba7b/unid/9042F3868F83AAB2C125802A005E17DC",
      "@link":
      {
          "rel":"document",
          "href":"/index.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/9042F3868F83AAB2C125802A005E17DC"
      },
      "@entryid":"2-9042F3868F83AAB2C125802A005E17DC",
      "@unid":"9042F3868F83AAB2C125802A005E17DC",
      "@noteid":"8FA",
      "@position":"2",
      "@siblings":5,
      "@form":"book",
      "author":"borislav peki\u0107",
      "title":"besnilo",
      "isbn":"3434233434",
      "stars":5
  },
  {
      "@href":"/index.nsf/api/data/collections/unid/93867b71911dd9b6c125802a005dba7b/unid/B5955CA4DB7621D6C125802A006A390A",
      "@link":
      {
          "rel":"document",
          "href":"/index.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/B5955CA4DB7621D6C125802A006A390A"
      },
      "@entryid":"4-B5955CA4DB7621D6C125802A006A390A",
      "@unid":"B5955CA4DB7621D6C125802A006A390A",
      "@noteid":"902",
      "@position":"4",
      "@siblings":5,
      "@form":"book",
      "author":"Harper Li",
      "title":"Ubiti pticu rugalicu",
      "isbn":"654646464564",
      "stars":4
  },
  {
      "@href":"/index.nsf/api/data/collections/unid/93867b71911dd9b6c125802a005dba7b/unid/FE2DBDAAA51892FCC125802A006A7A17",
      "@link":
      {
          "rel":"document",
          "href":"/index.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/FE2DBDAAA51892FCC125802A006A7A17"
      },
      "@entryid":"5-FE2DBDAAA51892FCC125802A006A7A17",
      "@unid":"FE2DBDAAA51892FCC125802A006A7A17",
      "@noteid":"906",
      "@position":"5",
      "@siblings":5,
      "@form":"book",
      "author":"Peki\u0107",
      "title":"Atlantida",
      "isbn":"5",
      "stars":3
  }
]

search works, but returns "entire page" and I cannot search by JSON fields. It looks like indexing did not split page to documents...

to make thing more clear, I want to automate something that can be done like this:

> wget http://localhost/index.nsf/api/data/collections/unid/93867b71911dd9b6c125802a005dba7b -O put.json
>
> bin/post -c gettingstarted put.json